# Using map to fit model to multiple datasets in a list

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to sample from a dataset, select columns, and fit a model to each sample.

```
library(bartMachine)
library(tidyverse)

    #dataset
    dat <- data.frame( x=rnorm(20, mean=5, sd=1), z=rnorm(20, mean=2, sd=0.5), y=rnorm(20, mean=6, sd=1), weight = rnorm(20, mean=1, sd=0.2) )
        #variable names 
        var1 <- dat %>% select(x, z) %>% names()
        var2 <- dat %>% select(y) %>% names()
        
        out <- tibble(run = 1:20) %>%
          mutate(
            data = map(run, ~ sample_n(dat, size = 5, weight = weight, replace = TRUE)),
            mdl = map(data[[run]], ~bartMachine(X=as.data.frame(.x) %>% select(all_of(var1)),
                                           y=as.data.frame(.x) %>% select(all_of(var2)) %>% unlist(), seed = 1)),
            smry = map(mdl, ~ summary(.x))
          )
```

Credit to @r2evans of helping with the above code

I get this error:

```
    Error in `mutate()`:
    ! Problem while computing `mdl = map(...)`.
    Caused by error in `data[[run]]`:
    ! recursive indexing failed at level 3
    Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Since `out$data[[1]]` gives me the first dataset in the list, why is `data[[run]]` not working?

Comment: I guess you need just `map(data, ~ ...` and not `map(data[[run]], ...`.  Reason is that `map` is looping over each element of the list.  When you do the subsetting with `[[run]]`, it is no longer a list of tibble, but just a tibble, and then it loop over each column of the tibble as a tibble is a list of columns

Comment: @akrun I can make this another post if more appropriate. When tibbles have different number of rows due to dropping NA's, I get this error: `Error in mutate():
! Problem while computing mdl =
  purrr::map(...).
Caused by error:
! arguments imply differing number of rows:`... Any advice around how to allow for data with different number of rows or why data must have the same dimensions?

Comment: Is the new error based on the same example or on a different one

Comment: A larger dataset but applying the same code.

Comment: It may be better to have a small reproducible example that gives the error with `dput` so that we can test it